# C# MediateR as a temporary Eventbus

Tags: c#, .net-core, domain-driven-design, microservices, mediator

I'm implementing an application with DDD approach and Microservices architecture, I'm going to publish an event after Command1 finished, Then i need to Command2 start automatically after the event published.
I'm working with limited resources so I can't use RabbitMq or other online event services.
I'm going to go ahead with this approach until new resources become available.
My Application contains two domain and I'm going to implement both of them as single service(it helps me to send event between them without any external Eventbus). With this approach I can separate theme into multiple services when I have enough resources.

My question is, Can i use Mediator to subscribe events? and in the feature replace it with a real eventbus.

My application is a web application, written using Asp.net core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MediatR allows you to decouple the inproc systems components communication so I think that could be possible to develop a handle that do things inproc and later change this code to just a line with `eventBus.publish(event)` but remember that MediatR is usually used for comamnds and what you have to model in this case are events so try to do no get too cognitive biased when developing the inproc model; always keep in mind that the objetive in the end, in this case, is publish events.

Answer (score 1):

Mediator is only within the process. It can't serve the purpose of EventBus.

EventBus is the buffer between services, so services are not flooded with events. You handler that subscribe to commands with Mediator will be notified straighaway and it's not the buffer.

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are using DDD then bounded context must be used to define your domain boundaries and cross domain communication must be done via intergration Events using some sort of buffer.

Have a look at DDD [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/ddd-oriented-microservice)

Comment: I think that the OP already knows that. He is trying decouple the 2 domains even inproc to anticipate the change from modular to microservices and make those changes frictionless.

Comment: I understand that but Mediator has completely different purpose . We can prove the point by doing this but it won't be frictionless later.